# Is CGLIB usable on Android?

Tags: java, android, cglib

Is it possible to use CGLIB in an Android application? I'm getting a VerifyError, and it seems from Googling that this could be because it was compiled on another JDK.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

CGLib will generate java byte code. Since Android runs Dalvik byte code, it won't work. You probably would be better off looking at [Dexmaker](http://code.google.com/p/dexmaker/) if you want to generate code dynamically for Android.

Answer (score 5):

This is a late answer but have a look at [Byte Buddy](http://bytebuddy.net) which is a library that I wrote and which is similar to cglib which in its newest version supports Android.